# Can I use Web Deploy to deploy a PHP application from IIS on Windows 7?

Tags: php, iis, deployment

The [Web Deploy 2.0 page](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy) on iis.net states the "Web Deploy Tool also enables administrators and delegated users to use IIS Manager to deploy ASP.NET and PHP applications to an IIS 7.0 server."

I'm (vaguely) familiar with using Web Deploy from Visual Studio to deploy an ASP.NET site. However I don't see a way to deploy a PHP site via IIS Manager.

The next page on [Installing and Configuring Web Deploy](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1075/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy/) states "The server must have an operating system that comes with IIS7— this means either Windows Server 2008 or Windows Server 2008 R2.".

I'm unsure if this is specifically for non-admin deploys or just means I cannot use IIS Manager for Web Deploy on Windows 7?

Is there a way to deploy a PHP site using Web Deploy on Windows 7 (my development machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these two pages.  They describe the packaging and deployment of PHP apps.
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/514/export-a-package-through-iis-manager/
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/515/import-a-package-through-iis-manager/

Comment: Thanks, I found that I needed to uninstall Web Deploy 2.0 and the management tool and then re-install using the msi installer to get the deploy actions available in IIS Manager. I also found I could successfully do a Web Deploy of a PHP project using Web Matrix.